# CLOB column and SQL Insert File

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, clob

I have to prepare a SQL Insert file which will have data exported from test to production instance. One of the column is CLOB in the table.

When I am doing a test run in UAT instance, I am getting the below error

> ORA-01704: string literal too long clob

What are the options available to create a SQL insert statement with CLOB as one of the column?

SQL script is the only option I have.

**Update 1**

If I save the insert statement in a file called test.sql and tried to execute from SQLPLUS as @D:\temp\test.sql it will give an error

> ORA-01704: string literal too long

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab
(
   prod_no            VARCHAR2 (100),
   prod_description   CLOB
);
```

**Insert statement**

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TEST_TAB
   (PROD_NO, PROD_DESCRIPTION)
 Values
   ('TEST_PROD', '
test

Symptoms and fault description: 

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2.  dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

5. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

6. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

7. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work carried out:

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date :13/07/2012  

Symptoms and fault description: 

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2.  dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

5. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

6. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

7. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
Work carried out:

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. Fault
dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work done by: 
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Date :09/10/2011  

Symptoms and fault description: 

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2.  dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work carried out:

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work done by: 
______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Date :29/03/2011  

Symptoms and fault description: 

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2.  dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work carried out:

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work carried out:

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work done by: dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Date :27-April -2010  

Symptoms and fault description: 

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work carried out:

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. Fdsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work done by: 






dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work done by: 
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________

Date :31-January-2010  

Symptoms and fault description: 

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
2.  dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work carried out:

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

2. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Work done by: 

_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Date :21-June-2009 

Symptoms and fault description: 

1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
2. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

3.dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

4. Edsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: So inshort your insert is failing and your guess is becuase of clob column. Right ?

Comment: What about sqlloader ?Can you use it?

Comment: @XING Yes that right, it is failing because of the CLOB column.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz How can I use SQLLoader to export data from test to production.

Comment: Can you please post your insert statement and some sample data and table DDL  to replicate the issue

Comment: @user75ponic to import.

Comment: @XING I have updated my question wiith table structure and data. Thanks

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz An example would be highly appreciable.

Comment: @user75ponic Do you have any tool to export clob column to separate files. Or do you have access to oracle db directory?

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz I am using TOAD to export CLOB data to a file.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz I do not have access to DB directory.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz SQLLoader is an option to import data.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz How to use SQLLoader to export data to UAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the amount of information provided you can use the below logic if you face the issue :

> ORA-01704: string literal too long clob

Try to split the characters into multiple chunks and then insert.

```
create table TBL (clob_col clob);
/    
INSERT INTO TBL (clob_col)
         VALUES (TO_CLOB ('chunk 1') || TO_CLOB ('chunk 2'));

where 'chunk 1' can be substr(data,1,32000).
      'chunk2   can be substr(data,32000)
```

See Demo:

```
DECLARE
   var   CLOB
      := 'Symptoms and fault description: 

            1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

            2.  dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

            3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

            4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

            3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

            4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
            Work carried out:

            1. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

            2. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

            3. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

            4. dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

            Work done by: dsdsdsdfdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd ';
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TBL (clob_col)
           VALUES (
                        TO_CLOB (SUBSTR (var, 1, 1000))
                     || TO_CLOB (SUBSTR (var, 1000, 2000)));

   COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: @user75ponic. isnt the solution i provided working for you. Try out and let me know

Comment: chunk1 will be from 1 - 32000 and chunk2 will be from 32000?

Comment: Its a example depending on the length of your data. You can make it small and try. So i mean to say, first take character from 1 to 200 and then in chunk2 take from 200 till end.. If it still gives the error then reduce the chunk size and add chunk3

Comment: I have a question, how will I create the following in insert statement? `TO_CLOB (substr(data,1,32000)) || TO_CLOB (substr(data,32000))`

Comment: @user75ponic . Check demo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137447/discussion-between-user75ponic-and-xing).

Comment: Did you try the solution i gave. What issue you faced.  I cannot chat since its blokced here at my workplace.

Comment: Your solution is fine. I have a question though. The SQL I have is an extract of insert statements . Not sure how to incorporate your solution after each insert statement.

Comment: You can close this question by accepting the solution and open a new question regarding that. I hope someone will surely help on your doubts

Comment: Thanks for the solution and insight. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Use toad to export each product description to separate files.  (right button on data grid -> Export Blobs(Raws,Longs)

2) Create control.ctl file. After `begindata` you have to add your prod_no and corresponding files, separate by commas. control.ctl and files have to be in the same directory.

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE *
append
   INTO TABLE test_tab
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   (prod_no        CHAR(100),
    file_name       FILLER char(200),
    prod_description    LOBFILE(file_name) TERMINATED BY EOF)
begindata
prod1,prod1.dat
prod2,prod2.dat
prod3,prod3.dat
```

3) Run sqlloader from cmd. `sqlldr user/password@tns_to_uat control=control.ctl`

Comment: Thanks for this. I have around 153899 rows in my table. So what is the best approach?

Comment: IMHO. Export everything with toad. And write a query (`select 'prod_no'||','||prod_no||'.dat' from test_tab;`) to generate `begindata` section. And be patient whole export and import can take a while.